# web.debug.config Transform not working

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web.config-transform

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I almost feel I've tried everything. I can't seem to get the web.config of my project to transform with my web.debug.config changes. I read someplace that transformation only takes place when being published. Then I read that SlowCheetah could handle this, so I installed it into my project. It doesn't make any difference either.

Running VS 2012 Express. I debug using the IIS Express local server that was installed by VS. I run Firefox as my browser.

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://development.mysite.com/" />
</appSettings>
```

web.debug.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://localhost:4652/"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

I've also tried using Replace:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://localhost:4652/"
      xdt:Transform="Replace"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

When running in Debug configuration locally:

```
string siteurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"];
```

Still results in siteurl being `http://development.mysite.com/`

I've ran Preview Transform by right clicking on the web.debug.config and it shows the transform being made perfectly, but not when I run the web application locally.

Have to admit, I don't see how to configure SlowCheetah. I don't see any way to configure it and I've been thinking maybe it does "something" on its own. :S

Does anyone know how to overcome this or if I might be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest ignoring slow cheetah for the moment because I don't think you need it. I've used it for Windows Forms development, but haven't had a need for web development. Instead use the standard one click web deploy mechanism, and rethink how you use config transforms.

Basically, only utilize transforms when you are publishing, and put your local development settings in your main Web.config instead of a transform.

1. Then if you have a lab/test/sandbox environment you want to publish to **create a solution and project configuration** for that environment.

[image: Adding a new solution configuration in Configuration Manager]

2. Next **right click on the Web.config and click Add Config Transform** to add a config transform for the solution configuration you just created.

[image: Adding a config transform]

3. Let's say you added a "Sandbox" solution configuration. If that's the case then a new file named Web.Sandbox.config will appear in Solution Explorer. Go ahead and update the values in Web.config and Web.Sandbox.config like so.

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://localhost:4652/" />
</appSettings>
```

Web.Sandbox.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://sandbox.mysite.com/"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
      xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

4. Finally, you need to make a "sandbox.mysite.com" (or whatever your URL really is) publish profile and **make sure that its Configuration is Sandbox** so that the Web.Sandbox.config transform is used during publish.

[image: Selecting the Sandbox Configuration in the Publish Web dialog]